# Converting data set into time series

Tags: r, time-series

How to convert the class data frame into time series?

This is the first 6 rows of my data.

```
 head(myData)


   Sales  Year
1    985  2016
2  2,385  2016
3  3,185  2016
4  2,385  2016
5  5,125  2016
6  2,385  2016
```

Currently the class is data.frame . I want to convert it into time series.

I ran this command

```
data.ts<- as.ts(myData)
```

and its showing the following results. Is this correct?

```
class(data.ts)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

Comment: It is difficult to transform it to a timeseries since all observations have the same year and no month or day is provided

Comment: no my observations actually have three years (2016, 2017 and 2018). These are just the first 6 rows of my observations. I also have Date and Month in my dataset. Should I include them as well?

Comment: Also, please tell how to convert it into time series?

Comment: yeah please include Date and Month as well

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help.